# size of multiple tabs in Notepad++

Tags: tabs, width, notepad++, multiline

this is my first question here. I am using Notepad++ and I love it. The only thing I find uncomfortable is that when multiple tabs are open, the width of the tab name is too big, and that is because Notepad in the tab name displays the full name of the file.

I wonder if it is possible that the with of the tab was automatically reduced (as it happens in Google Chrome, for example), so that the more tabs you have, the smaller the width of the tab, that is, the more abbreviated the name is.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe someone on [su] can help you but this doesn't seem like a programming question

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Notepad++ for a long time and I can say that there is no way to do what you want.

But, you can open multiple notapadd++ windows with multiple tabs.
e.g. 10 tabs at the 1st window, and 10 tabs at the 2nd window.

To open new Notepad++ window just drag&drop some tab from main window outside it. Same way you can move tabs between two windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I guess you have experienced too that when you have 20 tabs open it takes a long time to find a specific file. I wonder if it is possible to search among the open tabs for a file that is open. 

I think these kind of functionalities could be very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to have tabs resize like that. You can try settings>preferences>general>tab bar>reduce or even multi-line, but I don't believe they can dynamically resize.